# Django CreateView not creating a new user from 3 related models through ModelForm

Tags: python, django

I've created models in a Django project, one of which is an extended User model. Initially, I was creating a user through 2 forms, UserCreationForm and EmployeeForm based of a ModelForm, then using a function based view to validate the data and save it. It all worked fine until I tried to introduce the third form and wanted to use the CreateView.

Here are the models:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    SENIOR = 'Sr'
    JUNIOR = 'Jr'
    FIRST = 'I'
    SECOND = 'II'
    THIRD = 'III'

    GENERATIONAL_SUFFIX = [
        (SENIOR, 'Senior'),
        (JUNIOR, 'Junior'),
        (FIRST, 'First'),
        (SECOND, 'Second'),
        (THIRD, 'Third'),
    ]

    MALE = 'male'
    FEMALE = 'female'
    OTHER = 'other'

    SEX = [
        (MALE, 'Male'),
        (FEMALE, 'Female'),
        (OTHER, 'Other'),
    ]

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\d{11}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '09151234567'.")
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=11, blank=True)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=SEX, blank=True)
    suffix = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=GENERATIONAL_SUFFIX, blank=True)
    birthday = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    hire_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, default='blank_profile_picture.jpg')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    @property
    def get_full_name(self):
        first_name = self.user.first_name
        middle_name = self.middle_name
        last_name = self.user.last_name

        if middle_name is None:
            full_name = f'{first_name}{" "}{last_name}'
            return full_name
        else:
            full_name = f'{first_name}{" "}{middle_name}{" "}{last_name}'
            return full_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.get_full_name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_full_name

    
class EmployeePosition(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    position = models.ForeignKey(Position, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    position_change_reason = models.ForeignKey(PositionChangeReason, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='Hired As')
    effective_date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.position)
```

Here are the 3 forms:

```
class EmployeeRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control mb-2',
                                                                           'placeholder': 'juandelacruz@email.com'}))
    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control mb-2', 'placeholder': 'Juan'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control mb-2', 'placeholder': 'Dela Cruz'}))

    password1 = None
    password2 = None

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name']

    def clean(self):
        password = User.objects.make_random_password(length=10,
                                                  allowed_chars='abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ23456789')
        self.cleaned_data['password1'] = password
        self.cleaned_data['password2'] = password

        return super().clean()

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)

        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.is_active = False
        if len(user.first_name.split()) and len(user.last_name.split()) > 1:
            username = f'{"".join(user.first_name.split()[:2])}{"."}{"".join(user.last_name.split())}'
        elif len(user.first_name.split()) > 1:
            username = f'{"".join(user.first_name.split()[:2])}{"."}{user.last_name}'
        elif len(user.last_name.split()) > 1:
            username = f'{user.first_name}{"."}{"".join(user.last_name.split())}'
        else:
            username = f'{user.first_name}{"."}{user.last_name}'
        username = username.lower()
        user.username = username
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])

        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ['phone_number', 'middle_name', 'sex', 'suffix', 'birthday', 'hire_date']
        widgets = {
            'phone_number': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control mb-2', 'placeholder': '09151234567'}),
            'middle_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control mb-2', 'placeholder': 'Rodriguez'}),
            'suffix': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-select mb-2'}),
            'sex': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-select mb-2'}),
            'birthday': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date', 'class': 'form-control mb-2'}, format='%m/%d/%Y'),
            'hire_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date', 'class': 'form-control mb-2'}, format='%m/%d/%Y'),
        }

class EmployeePositionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    position_change_reason = forms.Select()
    effective_date = forms.DateField()

    class Meta:
        model = EmployeePosition
        fields = ['employee', 'position', 'position_change_reason', 'effective_date']
        widgets = {
            'position': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-select mb-2', 'id': 'position'}),
        }

    def check_position_change_reason(self):
        position_change_reason = self.cleaned_data['position_change_reason']
        if not position_change_reason:
            position_change_reason = EmployeePosition.position_change_reason.get_default()
        return position_change_reason

    def check_effective_date(self):
        effective_date = self.cleaned_data['effective_date']
        if not effective_date:
            effective_date = Employee.hire_date
        return effective_date

    def save(self, commit=True):
        position = super().save(commit=False)
        position.position_change_reason = self.cleaned_data['position_change_reason']
        position.effective_date = self.cleaned_data['effective_date']
        position.position = self.cleaned_data['position']
        return position
```

In the third form, I tried to set default values for two fields in case user doesn't enter them.

Here's how the view looks like:

```
class RegisterEmployeeView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = EmployeeRegistrationForm
    profile_form_class = EmployeeForm
    position_form_class = EmployeePositionForm
    template_name = 'accounts/register.html'
    success_url = '/'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(**self.get_form_kwargs())
        profile_form = self.profile_form_class(prefix='profile_form')
        position_form = self.position_form_class(prefix='position_form')
        return render(request, self.template_name,
                      {'form': form, 'profile_form': profile_form, 'position_form': position_form})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        profile_form = self.profile_form_class(request.POST)
        position_form = self.position_form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid() and position_form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            position_profile = position_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user
            position_profile.employee = profile.employee
            profile.save()
            position_profile.save()
            messages.success(self.request, f'{User.first_name}{" "}{User.last_name}{" was registered successfully."}')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
        else:
            context = {'form': form, 'profile_form': profile_form, 'position_form': position_form}
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

I've read dozens of articles here and other sites that have similar issues, but couldn't work it out. It seems similar to what [Risadinha said here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45938968/16021616): "it's not saving and not redirecting" := that is what happens when there is a validation error. But I can't wrap my head around this as I'm still learning Django.

**Update:**

I've followed Iain's suggestion to subclass the form as I'm planning to re-use the form. Would this be the right way to subclass it?

```
class EmployeeInitialPositionForm(EmployeePositionForm):

    class Meta:
        model = EmployeePosition
        exclude = ['employee']
```

Comment: Have you checked to see what validation errors your form(s) have? I imagine `EmployeePositionForm.employee` would have an error since you have that field on the form but won't have an Employee yet

Comment: Yes, you're right. I added a {{ position_form.employee.errors }} tag and it is showing that the field is required.

I thought that by not committing the save would help me avoid that until the user is saved in the view.

Comment: The field needs to have `required=False` if you are not going to submit a value for it in the POST

Comment: Since it is a related field, I can't add required=False in the model. In the admin this form field is shown as select field and in the ModelForm it doesn't accept it as an argument if I set the field as forms.Select.

Comment: You need to set it on the form, if the form is used else where and the field is required then you can make a subclass of it and just override the "employee" field with required=False on that subclass. Or exclude it from Meta.fields in that subclass

Comment: I've added a subclass and excluded the field employee from it but can't seem to find the way to add required=False. I edited my post to include the subclass.